# Making yaml/ruamel.yaml always dump lists inline

Tags: python, yaml

How do I make PyYAML or ruamel.yaml *always* dump lists inline? Be it lists of YAML elements loaded from an existing file or added from my code.

When I load YAML from a file and then dump it, it dumps lists inline (see code below). But if I add a new YAML element with lists to the existing parent object and then dump it, it dumps lists not inline.

I tried with Python 3.7.3, PyYAML 5.1.1 and ruamel.yaml 0.15.97.

```
>>> import ruamel.yaml
>>> ruamel.yaml.__version__
'0.15.97'
>>> raw_yaml = """
... users:
...   user1:
...     comment: comment1
...     keys: ["user1 key1", "user1 key2"]
...     groups: ["user1 group1", "user1 group2"]
... """
>>> yaml = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(raw_yaml, preserve_quotes=True)
>>> dump = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(yaml, default_flow_style=None)
>>> print(dump)
users:
  user1:
    comment: comment1
    keys: ["user1 key1", "user1 key2"]
    groups: ["user1 group1", "user1 group2"]
# So far so good, 'keys' and 'groups' are dumped inline
>>> yaml['users']['user2'] = {}
>>> yaml['users']['user2']['comment'] = 'comment2'
>>> yaml['users']['user2']['keys'] = []
>>> yaml['users']['user2']['keys'].append('user2 key1')
>>> yaml['users']['user2']['keys'].append('user2 key2')
>>> yaml['users']['user2']['groups'] = []
>>> yaml['users']['user2']['groups'].append('user2 group1')
>>> yaml['users']['user2']['groups'].append('user2 group2')
>>> dump = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(
...     yaml, default_flow_style=False, default_style="'",
...     indent=2, block_seq_indent=2)
# desired result:
# users:
#   user1:
#     comment: comment1
#     keys: ["user1 key1", "user1 key2"]
#     groups: ["user1 group1", "user1 group2"]
#   user2:
#     comment: comment2
#     keys: ["user2 key1", "user2 key2"]
#     groups: ["user2 group1", "user2 group2"]
>>> print(dump)
'users':
    'user1':
        'comment': 'comment1'
        'keys': ["user1 key1", "user1 key2"]
        'groups': ["user1 group1", "user1 group2"]
    'user2':
        'comment': 'comment2'
        'keys':
            - 'user2 key1'
            - 'user2 key2'
        'groups':
            - 'user2 group1'
            - 'user2 group2'
```

See above, when I dump just loaded YAML (users['user1']), the lists are inline:

```
keys: ["user1 key1", "user1 key2"]
groups: ["user1 group1", "user1 group2"]
```

But when I add users['user2'] and then dump entire YAML object, the lists are not inline:

```
'keys':
    - 'user2 key1'
    - 'user2 key2'
'groups':
    - 'user2 group1'
    - 'user2 group2'
```

If I set 'default_flow_style=True', it dumps the entire element inline:

```
'user2': {'comment': 'comment2', 'keys': ['user2 key1', 'user2 key2'], 'groups': [ 'user2 group1', 'user2 group2']}
```

This is not what I want. I want 'comment', 'keys' and 'groups' are dumped on separate lines with lists inline:

```
user2:
  comment: comment2
  keys: ["user2 key1", "user2 key2"]
  groups: ["user2 group1", "user2 group2"]
```

For PyYaml, the situation is practically the same.

I want lists are being always dumped inline (as for users['user1']). How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

What you call inline is called flow-style in the YAML
documentation. There is an option (`default_flow_style`) in both
ruamel.yaml to globally have everything flow-style,
everything block-style, or have leaf-nodes flow-style (rest block
style). This is the old behaviour of PyYAML.

However this is not what you want as that affect both sequences and
mappings, and you want mappings only.

`ruamel.yaml`, in round-trip-mode, can preserve individual
flow-style/block-style as they occur in your file, so you can have
e.g. leave nodes and their parents be flow-style, or all sequences
(Python lists) flow-style and all mappings (Python dicts) block-style
The latter of course only works as long as mapping is not "under" a
sequence, as you cannot have block style within flow-style.

If you start from scratch or with a loaded YAML that has the right format, 
just make sure any added lists are actually the special internal list subclass
that `ruamel.yaml` uses to preserve comments, style etc and set the flow-style
on the added lists

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from ruamel.yaml.scalarstring import DoubleQuotedScalarString as dq

def L(*l):
   ret = ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedSeq(l)
   ret.fa.set_flow_style()
   return ret   


raw_yaml = """\
users:
   user1:
    comment: comment1
    keys: ["user1 key1", "user1 key2"]
    groups: ["user1 group1", "user1 group2"]
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.indent(mapping=4, sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(raw_yaml)
data['users']['user2'] = {}
data['users']['user2']['comment'] = 'comment2'
data['users']['user2']['keys'] = L()
data['users']['user2']['keys'].append('user2 key1')
data['users']['user2']['keys'].append('user2 key2')
data['users']['user2']['groups'] = L('abc', L('user2 group1', dq('user2 group2')))
# print(data)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
users:
  user1:
    comment: comment1
    keys: ["user1 key1", "user1 key2"]
    groups: ["user1 group1", "user1 group2"]
  user2:
    comment: comment2
    keys: [user2 key1, user2 key2]
    groups: [abc, [user2 group1, "user2 group2"]]
```

Since you want **every** list to be represented as a flow style
sequence, it is also possible to change the representer for all lists,
by subclassing the Representer, but the above gives you finer control
and allows you to flow exactly those lists you want in flow-style.

---

`ruamel.yaml` (and PyYAML) use a streaming interface, doing
`print(dump(data))` instead of `dump(data, sys.stdout)` makes the dump
be done to a buffer in memory and then you stream that buffer. It is
inefficient in time and space, **don't do it**.

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please consider *accepting* it by clicking the ✔ (checkmark) next to the answer. That is the way other people know your problem has been solved, without reading the comments. It also changes the appearance of the question and this answer in lists. If a better answer comes along, you can always change the accepted answer.

Comment: this is great - any chance this will also work for dictionaries? with the given solution it converts those to list...

Comment: I think I got it: CommentedMap instead of CommentedSeq works. guess I still haven't figured out the peculiarities of ruamel semantics...

Comment: @mluerig If you want a dict like object you use `CommentedMap`, if you want a list like object `CommentedSeq`. Both have the `.fa` (flow attribute) that can be set to flow-style

Comment: @Anthon This answer and comments did solved my issue. This answer should be accepted answer actually

Answer (score 3):

I can only answer for PyYAML:
The behavior was changed in version 5.1.

https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/pull/256

`False` will output block style always.
`True` will output flow style always.
`None` will output flow style only for the collections which consists
only of scalars.

`False` is now the default because many users complained that the previous default `None` wasn't a good one.

So you want `default_flow_style=None` for PyYAML.

```
data = dict( a=dict(aa=dict(aaa = ['x','y']), ab=42) )
print( yaml.dump( data ) )
print( yaml.dump( data, default_flow_style=True ) )
print( yaml.dump( data, default_flow_style=False ) )
print( yaml.dump( data, default_flow_style=None ) )
```

Output:

````
a:
  aa:
    aaa:
    - x
    - y
  ab: 42

{a: {aa: {aaa: [x, y]}, ab: 42}}

a:
  aa:
    aaa:
    - x
    - y
  ab: 42

a:
  aa:
    aaa: [x, y]
  ab: 42```
````

Comment: tinita, thank you for your answer. I was going to say it works as I want, but I noticed one 'strange' thing. If I call dump() with 'default_flow_style=None' without any additional parameters to dump(), it works as I want.

But, as soon as I add default_style="'" parameter to dump (to wrap items in quotes), it starts dumping lists in block style even with 'default_flow_style=None'. You can try your own example - just add default_style="'" to the last dump().

Do you know why adding default_style changes dump behavior?

Comment: @VitalyFilatov I have the same problem. Need to quote the strings but have them on the same line. Anyone know a workaround?